# How To Get System Folder Path(C:\Windows C:\Program Files) in Windows using C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I am programming in C++ MFC and want to get the `C:\windows` and `c:\program files` paths programmatically.

Sometimes user may setup windows in other folder such as `c:\windows0`.

Is there any API to get absolute path of the windows and program files path?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

##### Using Win32 API

For the Windows folder:

```
TCHAR windir[MAX_PATH];
GetWindowsDirectory(windir, MAX_PATH);
```

For program files:

```
TCHAR pf[MAX_PATH];
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(
    0,
    pf, 
    CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES, 
    FALSE );
```

Where `MAX_PATH` comes from the Windows headers and will guarantee the buffer is long enough for the longest (non-UNC) path.

Also, note that `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` can be used to retrieve other "special" folder including the Windows folder just by replacing the third parameter to any from this [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

- [`GetWindowsDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getwindowsdirectoryw)
- [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderpathw)

Answer (score 5):

On Vista+, [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the replacement for `SHGetFolderPath` and `SHGetSpecialFolderPath`, although you can continue to use the older functions if you need backward compatibility to older versions of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Call [`getenv("%ProgramFiles%")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv) and [`getenv("%WinDir%")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv).

Comment: I would not be dependent on environment variables.

Comment: Never trust Enivronment Variables. As they are accessible to user. He might change it.

Comment: As for `SystemRoot` (== `%WinDir%`) the story is a little different. Certain environment variables get not set via the registry but by the loader when creating a Win32 process.

Answer (score 2):

Most of these come from `SHGetFolderPath`, but `GetSystemDirectory()` returns the absolute location of `C:\Windows\System32`. Don't use `GetWindowsDirectory()`. It doesn't do what you want anymore.

Comment: Would be more useful if you mentioned what aspect _doesn't do anymore_ what the inquirer asked.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: "On a system that is running Terminal Services, each user has a unique Windows directory. "

Comment: Thanks. Okay, I was mostly worried about the "anymore". Terminal Services have existed since Windows NT and only became more mainstream with fast user switching in XP then ...